# ffmpeg lock's up pc

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-editor, video-conversion, kdenlive

I have an i7-10700kx16. With 64g ram and 2 2tb SSD, The board is a z590-p. The video card is UHD 630 CML GT2. I install Ubuntu 23.04 and the ver of Ubuntu. Every time I to use Kdenlive or FFmpeg from ter. The pc lock's up until FFmpeg get done or Kdenlive. I have also tried it on an ASUS mini, same error. I have tried it with Wayland ans x11, same thing. So I tried it with fedora 38. It works just fine. I, all so tired NixOS no error just with ubuntu

Comment: Seems odd; for FFmpeg try a few variations of the `-threads <count>` option although this is not normally required. Cannot help with kdenlive I'm afraid...